# How to find table cell value based on click of cell on the same row?

Tags: jquery

I have an onclick event of a cell in my table, I would then like to be able to get the value of the cell which has a certain class name on it.

HTML:

```
<div class="table-responsive ManagementTableScroll">
    <table class="table table-bordered RoleTable" id="CreateEditRoleTable">
        <thead>
            <tr>
                <th>Permission Name</th>
                <th>Permission Type</th>
                <th>Permission Value</th>
                <th id="EditPermissionTableHead" style="display: table-cell;">Edit Permission</th>
                <th>Remove</th>
            </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody id="PendingPermissionsTableBody">
            <tr>
                <td class="TdCenter EditPermissionName">Export Amount</td>
                <td class="TdCenter EditPermissionType">Whole number</td>
                <td class="TdCenter EditPermissionValue">5</td>
                <td class="TdCenter">
                    <a class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil TdCenter" id="EditPermission" href="#">EditPermission</a>
                </td>
                <td class="TdCenter">
                    <a class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove TdCenter" id="RemoveRow" href="#"> RemoveRow </a>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
</div>
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).on("click", "#EditPermission", function () {
    $('#CreateOptionDD').val("Previous");
    $('#CreateOptionDD').trigger('change');
    $(this).find('.EditPermissionName').val();
});
```

I would have thought that this `$(this).find(classname)` would have found the value. But it returns undefined.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to find the table above (up the HTML tree) before filtering back down the tree. So change

```
$(this).find('.EditPermissionName').text();
```

to

```
$(this).closest('tr').find('.EditPermissionName').text();
```

`$(this).closest('tr')` should return the `<tr>` element. you then need to find the `.EditPermissionName` under this (`<td class="TdCenter EditPermissionName">`)

Comment: `.closest('tr')` would be better

Comment: @Liam you cannot be able to get the value inside the td using `.val()` you'll need to used `.html()`

Comment: True, though I think .text() would be more appropriate than .html()

Answer (score -2):

It is better to add an identifier on every row so it will be easy for you to get  and update any data within that row.

```
<div class="table-responsive ManagementTableScroll">
<table class="table table-bordered RoleTable" id="CreateEditRoleTable">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Permission Name</th>
            <th>Permission Type</th>
            <th>Permission Value</th>
            <th id="EditPermissionTableHead" style="display: table-cell;">Edit Permission</th>
            <th>Remove</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="PendingPermissionsTableBody">
        <tr id="unique-id-1"> 
            <input type="hidden" id="EditPermissionValue" value="5">
            <td class="TdCenter EditPermissionName">Export Amount</td>
            <td class="TdCenter EditPermissionType">Whole number</td> 
            <td class="TdCenter">5</td> 
            <td class="TdCenter"><a class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil TdCenter" id="EditPermission" href="#"></a></td> 
            <td class="TdCenter"><a class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove TdCenter" id="RemoveRow" href="#"></a></td> 
        </tr>
        <tr id="unique-id-2"> 
            <input type="hidden" id="EditPermissionValue" value="5">
            <td class="TdCenter EditPermissionName">Export Amount</td>
            <td class="TdCenter EditPermissionType">Whole number</td> 
            <td class="TdCenter">5</td> 
            <td class="TdCenter"><a class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil TdCenter" id="EditPermission" href="#"></a></td> 
            <td class="TdCenter"><a class="glyphicon glyphicon-remove TdCenter" id="RemoveRow" href="#"></a></td> 
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

You can create a hidden input and set the `EditPermissionValue` value in there and you can get the value via jquery like this.

```
 $(document).on("click", "#EditPermission", function () {
     var $row = $(this).closest("tr");

    $permission_value = $row.find('#EditPermissionValue').val();

    $('#CreateOptionDD').trigger('change');
});
```

Comment: *It is better to add an identifier on every row*. No it's not?!

Comment: @Liam Can you explain to me why its not better to add an identifier on every row? 
It's kinda rude that you just say that its not without giving any proper explanation or example for your basis.

Comment: Can you explain to me how this helps? Example of what? It's simply unnecessary bloat. How do you intend to create these unique identifiers? What if you want to add or remove rows, do you need to create new identifiers that your not using? If you can contextually traverse the tree what do the id's add?